# Trying to get value from textbox on index.php and use it on upload.php

Tags: javascript, php, file-upload

We have a simple upload application, just trying to upload files to a location using FTP, but before uploading the files we want users to enter in a name of a folder and we would create this folder then put the files in it.  We can successfully do this entering in static values, but we need to pull the text from the textbox 'foldername' on index.php and use the value of foldername on upload.php and are having no success with POST or GET.  Any help would be great.

index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Image upload</title>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Boogaloo'  rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<script  src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/multiupload.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var config = {
    support :  "image/jpg,image/png,image/bmp,image/jpeg,image/gif,text/plain,text/anytext,application/csv",        // Valid file formats
form: "demoFiler",                  // Form ID
dragArea: "dragAndDropFiles",   // Upload Area ID
uploadUrl: "upload.php"             // Server side upload url
}
$(document).ready(function(){
initMultiUploader(config);
});
</script>
<link href="css/style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body lang="en">
<center><h1 class="title">Multiple Drag and Drop File Upload</h1></center>
<div id="dragAndDropFiles" class="uploadArea">
<h1>Drop Images Here</h1>
</div>
<form method="POST" name="demoFiler" id="demoFiler" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload.php" >
Please name your folder: <input type="text" name="foldername" id="foldername"/></br>
<input type="file" name="multiUpload" id="multiUpload" multiple />
<input type="submit" name="submitHandler" id="submitHandler" value="Upload" class="buttonUpload" />
</form>
<div class="progressBar">
<div class="status"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

upload.php

```
<?php
$newdir = $_POST['foldername'];
$dir = '/1';
$connect = ftp_connect('server');
ftp_login($connect, 'user', 'password');
ftp_pasv($connect, true);
ftp_chdir($connect, $dir);
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST"){
    if (@ftp_chdir($connect, $newdir)){
         if (!empty($_FILES)) {
        $tempFile = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];          //3             
        $targetFile =  $_FILES['file']['name'];  //5
        ftp_put($connect, $targetFile, $tempFile, FTP_ASCII);
            }   

        }
        else
        {
        ftp_mkdir($connect, $newdir);
        ftp_chdir($connect, $newdir);
         if (!empty($_FILES)) 
            {
            $tempFile = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];          //3             
            $targetFile =  $_FILES['file']['name'];  //5
            ftp_put($connect, $targetFile, $tempFile, FTP_ASCII);
            }
        }


}
ftp_close($connect);

    echo($_POST['index']);
    exit;

?>
```

Comment: What happens when you try this? Can you do a simple echo of $newDir after setting it to make sure there is a value there?   Also, I would do some sort of cleaning of the name so that it is a valid directory name.

Comment: It is not getting any value for $newDir when we run this.

Comment: The problem would appear to be involving the multi uploader I would think, b/c just using that form and posting it to a upload.php I am able to get the value no problem

Comment: https://github.com/arunkumarsekar/Multiple_file_drag_and_drop_upload/tree/master/js   This is the javascript file we are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this is in multiupload.js you need to add a line to the _uploader function as such :

```
data.append('index',ids');
data.append('foldername', $('#foldername').val());
```

The foldername line is the line you need to add, should be around line number 72 based on the github version.